# Accessing DB from list adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-adapter

I have a listview that contains some data which I got from the web. Now I can make changes in the list item and once I make changes to the item, I am storing the updated value in the db. When i login in next time to the app, I am downloading the content from net and showing it in the listview with the changes that I have done last time. So my approach here is, I am querying the db for each item in the getview method of the list adapter to check for changes. Is it a good practice to do a db query for each item's getview method of the adapter? If not could you please suggest me some alternative. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that accessing the database from the adapter is a good idea. Consider implementing an interface .

Comment: No , I am getting the data online, making changes and storing them in sqlite device db.

Answer (score 2):

Never, really, never do that.

If you put your data download code in the getView method of the adapter it will make a network call for each row of the list.

Even worst, it will call it anytime that row appears on the screen, not only one time for row.

You should get all your data first, then use the adapter only to draw it.

You can at anytime call the db to check for changes and, if needed, notify the adapter to redraw the list to show the changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, I am not making a webcall from the getView. Its only the Sqlite db query. Fetch rows from db.

Answer (score 1):

In Android development, any time you want to show a vertical list of items you will want to use a ListView which is populated using an Adapter to a data source. When we want the data for the list to be sourced directly from a SQLite database query we can use a CursorAdapter.

[image]

The CursorAdapter fits in between a Cursor (data source from SQLite query) and the ListView (visual representation) and configures two aspects:

1. Which layout template to inflate for an item
2. Which fields of the cursor to bind to views in the template

**Creating the View Template**

When we want to display a series of items into a list using a custom representation of the items, we need to use our own custom XML layout template for each item. We can simply create an XML layout template in `res/layout/item_todo.xml` representing a particular cursor row:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Study cursors"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPriority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Defining the Adapter**

```
public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ViewAdapter() { 
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        } 

        @Override 
        public int getCount() { 
            return favoriteList.size(); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null; 
        } 

        @Override 
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        } 

        @Override 
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem,null);
            } 

            final TextView nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
            nameText.setText("Name : "+favoriteList.get(position).getName());
            final TextView ageText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ageText);
            ageText.setText("Age : "+favoriteList.get(position).getAge());

            final Button edit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.row);
                    dialog.setTitle("Add Data to Database");
                    final EditText name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    final EditText age = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.age);
                    Button Add = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Add);
                    Add.setText("Add");
                    Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override 
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if(name.getText().toString() != null && name.getText().toString().length() >0 ){
                                if(age.getText().toString() != null && age.getText().toString().length() >0 ){
                                    db.updateRow(favoriteList.get(position).getId(), name.getText().toString(), age.getText().toString());
                                    favoriteList = db.getFavList(); 
                                    listView.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter()); 
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }else{ 
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter the Age", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                                } 
                            }else{ 
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter the Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                            } 
                        } 
                    }); 
                    dialog.show();  
                } 
            }); 
            final Button delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    db.removeFav(favoriteList.get(position).getId());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    favoriteList = db.getFavList(); 
                    listView.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter()); 
                } 
            }); 
            return convertView;
        } 
    }
```

Create database

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Database Version 
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //Database Name 
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Test";
    //Table Name 
    private static final String TABLE_TEST = "TestTable";
    //Column Name 
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    } 

    //Create Table 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEST + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_AGE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TEST);
        onCreate(db);
    } 

    //Insert Value 
    public void adddata(Context context,String movieId,String songId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, movieId);
        values.put(KEY_AGE, songId); 
        db.insert(TABLE_TEST, null, values);
        db.close(); 
    } 

    //Get Row Count 
    public int getCount() { 
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEST;
        int count = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
            count = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
        }    
        return count;
    } 

    //Delete Query 
    public void removeFav(int id) {
        String countQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_TEST + " where " + KEY_ID + "= " + id ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(countQuery);
    } 

    //Get FavList 
    public List<FavoriteList> getFavList(){
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        List<FavoriteList> FavList = new ArrayList<FavoriteList>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do { 
                FavoriteList list = new FavoriteList();
                list.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                list.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                list.setAge(cursor.getString(2));
                FavList.add(list);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } 
        return FavList;
    }
```

}

Enojoys.... :)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use cursor adapter to bind the list view.You can use Loader to get the list updated even if there is a change in the data base.
onLoadFinished (Loader loader, D data) of the Loader call back would be  monitor for changes to the data, and report them to you through new calls. You should not monitor the data yourself.